# How to check for particular text irrespective of the font of the text in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a code piece as:

```
If Sheets("Data").Cells(27, 3).Value = "Date" Then
```

Even after having "**Date**" in particular Cell this `If` loop doesn't works. After lot of digging I found that Excel in which I am searching is using some pre-defined font. If I delete the text "Date" already printed in the report and put my text as "Date", same code piece works perfectly. Please suggest way to make this codepiece work.

Comment: Are there any leading or trailing spaces? If so, try `If Trim(Sheets("Data").Cells(27, 3).Value) = "Date" Then`

Comment: The value of a cell has nothing to do with its font. In addition to the leading/trailing spaces issue, your test is case-sensitive.

Comment: I would probably test for `UPPER(Sheets("Data").Cells(27, 3).Value = "DATE"` as well as the `Trim` advised above for a belt & braces approach.

Comment: Have a look at the `Like` operator as well: `If Sheets("Data").Cells(27, 3).Value Like "*Date*" Then`

Comment: I know its strange,but definitely some issue with FONT. Thanks Zac!, LIKE somehow is working fine though I have to edit IF clause in this case.